# Using ember-qunit to test controllers with a store (DS.FixtureAdapter)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-qunit

I have an ember-qunit test case for a controller (using `moduleFor('controller:name', ...)`) that that I'd like to be able to use the `moduleForModel`-exclusive `this.store()` in order to retrieve a DS.FixtureAdapter data store. For this specific test case, I'm not trying to test the model - I just want to verify that the controller can be populated with a set of model instances and various operations can be run against that data.

I'm using coffeescript so my code looks like:

```
moduleFor("controller:test", 'My Controller', {
  setup: ->
    @store().createRecord 'test', value: 1
    @store().createRecord 'test', value: 2

    @subject({
      model: @store().all('test')
    })
  teardown: -> App.reset()
}, (container, context) ->
  container.register 'store:main', DS.Store
  container.register 'adapter:application', DS.FixtureAdapter
  context.__setup_properties__.store = -> container.lookup('store:main')
)
```

In the example above there is a controller named TestController and there is also a model named Test. I lifted the `container.register` and `context.__setup_properties__.store` lines from the definition of `moduleForModel` in ember-qunit.

The problem is that I get an error when running the ember-qunit test suite:

```
Setup failed on [test case name]: No model was found for 'test'
```

Running the actual application outside of ember-qunit works fine. Maybe there's somebody out there who's had this same issue? Or maybe I'm taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem could be that your test model has not been registered in the container, so it cannot be resolved.

You could register manually during your test module callbacks:

```
container.register('model:test', TestModel)
```

Or use the needs property of the moduleFor impl:

```
moduleForComponent('controller:test', 'My Controller', {

  // specify the other units that are required for this test
  needs: ['model:test'],
  setup: {...},
  teardown: {...}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, what's missing was the `needs` field. It works!